# SQL- Запрос, сортирока с условием

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день!

Есть вопрос, как отобразить список студентов, которые хотят изучать дисциплину, код которой вводится с клавиатуры. ***Если количество претендентов превышает L (= 8), тогда будут отображаться только первые ученики L, которые имеют более высокий средний балл;***
Интересует именно как ставить условие сортировке.

Comment: *код которой вводится с клавиатуры* SQL Server не имеет средств ввода с клавиатуры.

Comment: `SELECT TOP L` как вывод L строк в начале и в конце `Order by column` как сортировка по колонке column.

Comment: Про ввод с клавиатуры уже знаю, здесь имеется ввиду сразу указывать  в условии.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Пожалуйста отметьте как ответ, если он вам помог

Comment: @Akina, если используется Management Studio, тогда можно создать процедуру, выбрать команду Выполнить в браузере объектов и ввести параметры с клавиатуры. Т.е. при желании можно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В начале запроса `SELECT TOP L` как вывод L строк

И в конце `Order by column` как сортировка по колонке column